# C# - Add a default value to a column after the AddingNew of the dataBindingSource

Tags: c#, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

When I insert a new row in the dataBindingSource I would like to assign a default value to a field so that if the user did not enter any value this value would be assigned by default. I can not leave this default value in the database because it may vary depending on the occasion.

So, after the user hit the insert button, using a dataBindingSource, how can I assign a column (in the new row being inserted) to a default value (pre determined)? I thought about using the AddingNew event of the dataBindingSource.

I am using a dataSet with bindingSource and tableAdapter. I accept other suggestions for approach.

Comment: Did you use DataTable object ?

Comment: No, I did not. My form just have this follows data controls: a dataSet, a tableAdapter and a bindingSource. But I accept any suggestions about my above problem.

Comment: You can also set a default value in the dataset designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) object, then you can easily set a default value for such column :

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Columns["Column1"].DefaultValue = "default";
  // dt.DataSet = ..
```